# Using a counter in WP_query to display posts in different DIVs

Tags: php, wordpress, counter, posts

I am trying to display 11 posts per page, in this order 1-3-2-3-2. I think the easiest way is to use a counter, I know how it works in general but I haven't done it with a query before, so any help is appreciated. There is not much on the page, just pagination and 11 said posts, I just need to get this to work and I'm pretty satisfied!

Here is the code for the whole section:

```
<section class="blog-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="blog-inner">

            <?php
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $args = array(
                'paged' => $paged,
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories(get_the_ID()),
                'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID()),
                'posts_per_page' => 11,
                'orderby' => 'date',
            );


            $related_query = new WP_Query($args);
            ?>

            <?php if ($related_query->have_posts()) { ?>

                <div class="posts-grid">

                    <?php while ($related_query->have_posts()) : ?>

                        <?php $related_query->the_post(); ?>

                        <div class="grid-item">

                            <a class="item-thumbnail" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumb-small'); ?></a>

                            <p class="item-post-date"><?php echo get_the_date('l jS F, Y'); ?></p>

                            <h4 class="item-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>

                            <p class="item-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

                            <a class="more-link link-with-arrow" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e('READ MORE', 'amendment-cycles'); ?></a> <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>

                        </div>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                </div>

                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            <?php } ?>

            <div class="blog-pagination">
                <ul>
                    <li><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; PREV', $related_query->max_num_pages) ?></li>
                    <li><?php next_posts_link('NEXT &raquo;', $related_query->max_num_pages) ?></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: So the `posts-grid` div is the one you want to create multiples of here? Easiest if you use a loop counter (starting at 0 for the first item), and then use `if(in_array($counter, [1, 4, 6, 9, 11])) { echo '</div><div>'; }` to close the current div, and open a new one. The values inside the array are simply your numbers of elements per group, added up.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You gave me an idea, so I managed to do it my own way:

<?php 
 $counter= 0;
 while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
 $counter++;
 if ($counter<2) {
    <div class="featured-post">
    ...
    </div>
 }
 //code for other div styles etc.
 endwhile;
 ?>

It was pretty simple, I was just confused about something. Thanks again.